# Java classpath still the same after changing .bashrc

Tags: java, linux, classpath

Is there a clear instruction available on how to set the classpath properly for updating the java jdk and the java vm?

On my system is Java 1.7 installed but I need the features of Java 8!

So I did the following steps as mentioned in the official Oracle classpath guide and other tutorials but it just doesn't work for me:

1.) moved the jdk to /usr/lib

2.) added the following lines to the ~/.bashrc:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

I type `which java`

Output is `/usr/bin/java` which is still the old 1.7 jdk

The runtime (VM) is not the official form Oracle but the openJDK so I also need to update this one to version 8...

Comment: Try starting a new shell...

Comment: Your trying to update the bash path, the classpath is a different variable, that points javac/java to where to find classes (generally in the form of jars).

Comment: @janos yes, it does. It is my java vm. I also tried to edit the .bash_profile (which didn't exist) like explained here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/ no success... I'm on Debian 8 by the way. It's ridiculous how hard it seems to get this done...